# Stop jQuery Datepicker from refreshing when clicking previous/next month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following problem: I'm using jQuery Datepicker so that a user can select flight dates. The only problem I am facing is that when a user selects the dates, and then clicks the top arrows to go to the previos or next months, then the dates(red colored) which the user selects, go back to the original. How can I fix this? Please help. I am providing a **Fiddle:  [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yF8Qr/)**
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var start_date = "2014-10-04";
    var end_date = "2014-10-20";
    var date1 = new Date(start_date);
    var date2 = new Date(end_date);
    var actual_end_date = new Date(end_date);
    actual_end_date.setDate(actual_end_date.getDate() + 2);
    var pre_nights = 1;
    var post_nights = 2;
    var msecPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
    if (post_nights > 0) {
        date2 = new Date(date2.getTime() + (msecPerDay * post_nights));
    }


    var flight_end = new Date(date2.getTime() + msecPerDay);
    if (pre_nights > 0) {
        date1 = new Date(date1.getTime() - (msecPerDay * pre_nights));
    }



    var post_night_dates_arr = [];
    var pre_night_dates_arr = [];

    function date_check() {
        $(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
        $('.ui-datepicker-group').each(function () {
            $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:has(a)').each(function () {
                var this_elem = $(this);
                var this_date = new Date($(this).data('year') + "-" + ($(this).data('month') + 1) + "-" + $(this).text());
                var this_end_date = new Date(this_date);
                this_end_date.setDate(this_end_date.getDate() + 1);
                var current_this_end_date = this_end_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (this_end_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + this_end_date.getDate()).slice(-2);

                var current_day = this_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (this_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + this_date.getDate()).slice(-2);

                if (pre_night_dates_arr.length > 0 || post_night_dates_arr.length > 0) {
                    $.each(pre_night_dates_arr, function (key, val) {
                        if (current_day === val) {
                            this_elem.addClass("extra_nights_color");
                        }
                    });
                    $.each(post_night_dates_arr, function (key, val) {
                        if (current_this_end_date === val) {
                            this_elem.addClass("extra_nights_color");
                        }
                    });
                }


            });
        });
    }

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: date1,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var current_day = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var flight_start = date1.getFullYear() + "-" + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + date1.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var flight_end_mod = flight_end.getFullYear() + "-" + (flight_end.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + flight_end.getDate()).slice(-2);
            if (current_day == flight_start) {
                var arr = [true, "flight_dept_color"];
            } else if (date > date1 && date < date2) {
                if (pre_nights > 0) {
                    pre_night_dates_arr.push(current_day);
                    pre_nights--;
                    var arr = [true, "extra_nights_color"];
                } else if (post_nights > 0) {
                    var flight_end_date = new Date(flight_end);
                    flight_end_date.setDate(flight_end_date.getDate() - post_nights);
                    var flight_end_date_mod = flight_end_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (flight_end_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + flight_end_date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    if (current_day == flight_end_date_mod) {
                        post_night_dates_arr.push(current_day);
                        post_nights--;
                        var arr = [true, "extra_nights_color"];
                    } else {
                        var arr = [true, "tour_dates_color"];
                    }

                } else {
                    var arr = [true, "tour_dates_color"];
                }
            } else if (current_day == flight_end_mod) {
                var arr = [true, "flight_return_color"];
            } else {
                var arr = [true, ""];
            }
            return arr;
        },
        onSelect: function (dateStr, inst) {
            inst.inline = false;
            date_check();
            console.log("test");
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:has(a)").each(function () {

                var this_date = $(this).data('year') + "-" + ("0" + ($(this).data('month') + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + $(this).text()).slice(-2);
                var date2_mod = date2.getFullYear() + "-" + (date2.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + date2.getDate()).slice(-2);

                if (pre_night_dates_arr.length > 0) {
                    if (this_date < pre_night_dates_arr[0]) {
                        if (this_date == dateStr) {
                            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_dept_color").removeClass("flight_dept_color");
                            $(this).addClass("flight_dept_color");
                        }
                    } else if (this_date > date2_mod) {
                        if (this_date == dateStr) {
                            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_return_color").removeClass("flight_return_color");
                            $(this).addClass("flight_return_color");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    var flight_start = date1.getFullYear() + "-" + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + ("0" + date1.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    if (this_date <= flight_start) {
                        if (this_date == dateStr) {
                            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_dept_color").removeClass("flight_dept_color");
                            $(this).addClass("flight_dept_color");
                        }
                    } else if (this_date > date2_mod) {
                        if (this_date == dateStr) {
                            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_return_color").removeClass("flight_return_color");
                            $(this).addClass("flight_return_color");
                        }
                    }
                }


            });
        }

    });
    date_check();
    $('.ui-corner-all').on('click', function (e) {
        date_check();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you work on narrowing the problem and your code down?

Comment: I either do not understand or cannot reproduce the issue. Can you clarify?

Comment: basically when a user selects a date before the "tour dates" it should higlight red, which works. But the problem happens when this date is selected and then you click on the previous/next month arrow. when these are clicked, the selected red dates go back to the initial one. Is there a way to disable this "refresh" behaviour when the prev/next buttons are clicked?

Comment: I figured it out.. I had to redo the code. It seems that the "beforeShowDay" option for the datepicker was not as beneficial. What I ended up doing is just placing all the calls outside of the datepicker widget. I ended up delegating s click event to the .ui-datepicker-prev / next as this seemed to work better.  Thanks for the people who viewed and actually tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution. Thanks for whoever took the time to look over this. Let me know if you can re modify this code even better.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var selected_dept_date = "";
            var selected_return_date = "";

            var actual_start_date = "2014-10-04";
            var actual_end_date = "2014-10-20";

            var actual_end_date_DATE = new Date(actual_end_date);
            actual_end_date_DATE.setDate(actual_end_date_DATE.getDate() + 1);


            var time = "T00:00:00";
            var start_date = actual_start_date + time;
            var end_date = actual_end_date + time;

            var date1 = new Date(start_date);
            var date2 = new Date(end_date);


            var pre_nights = 5;
            var post_nights = 2;

            var pre_nights_count = pre_nights;
            var post_nights_count = post_nights;
            var msecPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);


            function getAllDays(d1, d2) {
                var s = new Date(d1);
                s.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var e = new Date(d2);
                e.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var a = [];
                while (s < e) {
                    a.push(s);
                    s = new Date(s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1));
                }
                return a;
            }


            var pre_night_dates_arr = [];
            var post_night_dates_arr = [];


            if (pre_nights > 0) {
                date1 = new Date(date1.getTime() - (msecPerDay * pre_nights));

                $.each(getAllDays(date1, date2), function(key, val) {
                    if (pre_nights_count > 0) {
                        pre_night_dates_arr.push(val);
                        pre_nights_count--;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }


            if (post_nights > 0) {
                date2 = new Date(date2.getTime() + (msecPerDay * post_nights));
                $.each(getAllDays(date1, date2), function(key, val) {
                    if (post_nights_count > 0) {

                        if (val.getTime() > actual_end_date_DATE.getTime()) {
                            post_night_dates_arr.push(val);
                            post_nights_count--;
                        }

                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            var start_date_after_settings = new Date(getAllDays(date1, date2)[0]);
            start_date_after_settings.setDate(start_date_after_settings.getDate() - 1);

            var end_date_after_settings = new Date($(getAllDays(date1, date2)).last()[0]);
            end_date_after_settings.setDate(end_date_after_settings.getDate() + 1);


            function load_tour_dates() {
                $(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
                $('.ui-datepicker-group').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:has(a)').each(function() {
                        var this_elem = $(this);
                        var this_date = new Date(this_elem.data('year') + "," + (this_elem.data('month') + 1) + "," + ("0" + this_elem.text()).slice(-2));
                        $.each(getAllDays(date1, date2), function(key, val) {

                            if (pre_night_dates_arr.length > 0) {
                                $.each(pre_night_dates_arr, function(key2, val2) {
                                    if (this_date.getTime() == val2.getTime()) {
                                        this_elem.addClass("extra_nights_color");
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            if (this_date.getTime() == val.getTime()) {
                                this_elem.addClass("tour_dates_color");
                                return false;
                            }

                            if (post_night_dates_arr.length > 0) {
                                $.each(post_night_dates_arr, function(key2, val2) {
                                    if (this_date.getTime() == val2.getTime()) {
                                        this_elem.addClass("extra_nights_color");
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        });
                    });
                });
            }

            function load_selected_start_dates() {

                $('.ui-datepicker-group').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:has(a)').each(function() {
                        var this_elem = $(this);
                        var this_date = new Date(this_elem.data('year') + "," + (this_elem.data('month') + 1) + "," + ("0" + this_elem.text()).slice(-2));
                        if (selected_dept_date instanceof Date) {
                            if (this_date.getTime() == selected_dept_date.getTime()) {
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_dept_color");
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (this_date.getTime() == start_date_after_settings.getTime()) {
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_dept_color");
                            }
                        }

                        if (selected_return_date instanceof Date) {
                            if (this_date.getTime() == selected_return_date.getTime()) {
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_return_color");
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (this_date.getTime() == end_date_after_settings.getTime()) {
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_return_color");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });


            }

            function select_date(date) {

                var curr_date_mod = new Date(date);

                $('.ui-datepicker-group').each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td:has(a)').each(function() {
                        var this_elem = $(this);
                        var this_date = new Date(this_elem.data('year') + "," + (this_elem.data('month') + 1) + "," + ("0" + this_elem.text()).slice(-2));

                        if (curr_date_mod.getTime() <= start_date_after_settings.getTime()) {
                            if (this_date.getTime() === curr_date_mod.getTime()) {
                                selected_dept_date = curr_date_mod;
                                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_dept_color").removeClass("flight_dept_color");
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_dept_color");
                            }
                        }

                        if (curr_date_mod.getTime() >= end_date_after_settings.getTime()) {
                            if (this_date.getTime() === curr_date_mod.getTime()) {
                                selected_return_date = curr_date_mod;
                                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .flight_return_color").removeClass("flight_return_color");
                                this_elem.addClass("flight_return_color");
                            }
                        }

                    });
                });

            }

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                defaultDate: date1,
                onSelect: function(dateStr, inst) {
                    inst.inline = false;

                    var curr_date = dateStr.replace("-", ",");
                    var curr_date_mod = new Date(curr_date);

                    select_date(curr_date_mod);

                }

            });

            function must_runs() {

                load_tour_dates();

                load_selected_start_dates();
                if (selected_dept_date instanceof Date) {
                    select_date(selected_dept_date);
                }

                if (selected_return_date instanceof Date) {
                    select_date(selected_dept_date);
                }

            }

            must_runs();

            $(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-prev', 'click', function() {
                must_runs();
            });
            $(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-next', 'click', function() {
                must_runs();
            });



        });
```